# Rust visibility from child module to outside

Tags: rust, struct, visibility, rust-rustlings

I'm learning about Rust, and trying to figure out the visibility rules for modules.
I have the following code:

```
fn x() -> u8 {
    5
}

struct Person {
    name: String,
}

mod example {
    use super::{x, Person};

    pub fn foo(person: &Person) {
        println!("{}", x());
        println!("Person with name: {}", person.name);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let person = Person{name: String::from("PersonName")};
    example::foo(&person);
}
```

Which throws the following error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0446]: private type `Person` in public interface
  --> src/main.rs:12:5
   |
5  | struct Person {
   | ------------- `Person` declared as private
...
12 |     pub fn foo(person: &Person) {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't leak private type

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0446`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

1. From my understanding, children submodules should have visibility to the symbols from the parent module.
   I'm not sure why I need to mark `Person` as public.
2. If I mark `Person` as public the code executes, but my next question is, why I don't have to mark the `x()` function as public also, as it is used at the same place with the `Person` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the module `example` it's not known that the module is only visible to `super` it also might have been reexported somewhere completely different in `main.rs`:

```rust
pub mod completely_diffrent {
    pub use super::example;
}
```

which would be difficult or even impossible to track.

A solution other than making `Person` public is to mark the function public only to `super`:

```rust
mod example {
    use super::{x, Person};

    pub(super) fn foo(person: &Person) {
        println!("{}", x());
        println!("Person with name: {}", person.name);
    }
}
```

Which avoids all those pitfalls and thus compiles as you can see on the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=10a8acaff5d9df5572a2266d69085063)

For why you'd have to mark `Person` as public but not `x` the reason is that `Person` appears in the signature of `foo`: `fn(&Person)` while `x` does not.